# How to tell if the AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor is loaded on the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor on my page, but depending on certain variables the editor's Visible control can be set to false in code-behind. I'm getting a reference to the HTMLEditor in Javascript like so

```
var email = $get('<%=TemplateEditor.ClientID%>').control;
```

but I need a way to tell if the control is loaded on the page or not. If it's not, I don't want to call the code above because it will error out. Can anyone tell me how to test in Javascript if the control is loaded on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check for the existence of `Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor` on the page. I don't think the scripts are loaded if the editor isn't visible.

```
if(typeof Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor !== "undefined") {
     // editor exists on page
}
```

EDIT

Tinkering with the javascript console `$get()` seems to return null if `$get()` cannot find the control by the ID you provided. Maybe try :

```
var editor = $get('<%=TemplateEditor.ClientID%>');
if(editor !== null) {
    var email = editor.control;
    // you'll probably want to do more processing here.
}
```

Comment: But, if exists another HTMLEditor in the page (and is Visible), the error throw again..

Comment: Didn't think about multiple editor support. I updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: Thanks, Steven, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've used your second suggestion and it works beautifully. I haven't tested your first suggestion, but if there's only one HTMLEditor on the page, I imagine it would work very nicely too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad trick, but i think work..

Place an `<asp:HiddenField>` into the page, and set the Value property to "True" or "False" from code behind where you change the Visible property of TemplateEditor.

After, simply:

```
var isVisible = $get('<%=HiddenField.ClientID%>').value;
var email;

if (hiddenFieldValue == "True")
    email = $get('<%=TemplateEditor.ClientID%>').control;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This had actually occurred to me, and I was looking for a more "official" solution, but it will work. Thanks!